# MaterialDrawer set selected profile

Tags: java, android, materialdrawer

I use the [MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) library by Mike Penz.

In my OnCreate, profiles are added to the drawer from a linkedHashMap. When a profile gets selected, the new selected profile is saved in a sharedPreference.

**My Question**: if I launch the App again, how can I set the profile, whichs name is stored in the sharedPreference, as the selected?

**Edit**: Without an identifier? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MaterialDrawer` **requires** an `identifier` given to it's elements so that you can reselect them (and that the `Drawer` itself can re-select them upon configuration changes) again.

Simply provide any id. You can use something like this:

```
private static long hashString64Bit(CharSequence str) {
    long result = 0xcbf29ce484222325L;
    final int len = str.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        result ^= str.charAt(i);
        result *= 0x100000001b3L;
    }
    return result;
}
```

To generate an long identifier for your `string`, or you generate some kind of hashcode.